# Cpp flags in Android JNI - change variable based on flag

Tags: android, c++, cmake, java-native-interface

I would like to pass variable to cpp library in android module in order to achieve something like that:

```
//imports..
using namespace std;

extern "C" {

bool logsEnabled = false;

#ifdef LOGS
logsEnabled = true;
#endif

void android_log(const char *text) {
    if (logsEnabled) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "TAG", "%s", text);
    }
} ;

//other methods declaration
```

CppFlags are passed in gradle:

```
android{
 defaultConfig{
    externalNativeBuild{
      cmake{
           cppFlags '-DLOGS'
```

Unfortunelly the compiler doesn't see daclaration for logsEnabled in block #ifdef - #endif:

```
Error:(27, 1) error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for something like:

```
#ifdef LOGS
bool logsEnabled = true;
#else
bool logsEnabled = false;
#endif
```

Or perhaps just simpler:

```
void android_log(const char *text) {
#ifdef LOGS
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "TAG", "%s", text);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Had to add **const** before bool logsEnabled for variable visibility in android_log.